# SOQL query in a javascript button

Tags: soql, javascript, custom-button, parameters

On Contract object, i have a javascript button, which is supposed to pass the ID the related opportunity and account as a parameter to a page. How do i handle scenarios where SOQL query fails to return anything.

There is a custom junction object that relates contract and opportunity.

**Details of the junction object-**

```
API Name - OpportunityContract__c
Fields - ContractId__c  Lookup(Contract)
         OpportunityId__c   Master-Detail(Opportunity)
```

My code for javascript button on contract object -

```
var contractOppJuncObj= sforce.connection.query("SELECT OpportunityId__c from OpportunityContract__c where ContractId__c='{!Contract.Id}'");

var records = contractOppJuncObj.getArray("records");

var opptyID = records[0].OpportunityId__c;

window.open('/apex/test_page?opportunityid='+opptyID+'&accountid={!Contract.AccountId}','_blank')
```

There could be contracts which are not related to opportunity at all. I dont want my button to pop errors. Just pass opportunityId as blank.

Comment: Are multiple records being returned and the first one is not the one you expected?

Comment: Ignore it. I got it. Yes, there are multiple records. I know how to handle that. I was gonna post follow question regarding error handling scenarios as well.

Incase query fails to return anything (there could be some contracts with no related opportunities). Instead of my javascript button throwing errors, i just want the parameters to be blank. How do i do that?

I will update my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you should put a guard condition around the case you expect might be failing. So if you expect that records might by empty in some scenarios, build a guard condition around that:

```
var contractOppJuncObj= sforce.connection.query("SELECT OpportunityId__c from OpportunityContract__c where ContractId__c='{!Contract.Id}'");

var records = contractOppJuncObj.getArray("records");

// default value of opptyID is empty string    
var opptyID = "";
if(records != null && records[0] != null)  {
    // if there are OpportunityContract records, take the OppID of the first record
    opptyID = records[0].OpportunityId__c;
}

window.open('/apex/test_page?opportunityid='+opptyID+'&accountid={!Contract.AccountId}','_blank');
```

Hope it helps.